# Qt CSS border + padding seems to cut off text

Tags: css, qt

I have several `QPushButton`s that are located beside each other. Each button has a padding of *8px* on the left and the right side. When one of them has focus I change the background-color. So far it looks fine:

[image]

In addition to the background-color change I want to apply a border of 2px in white. When I do that the text seems to be cut off by the size of my border. So with a border of 2px it looks like this:

[image]

When I increase the border-size to, for example, 4px my text vanishes completely because the button does not increase it's size correctly.

I use the following CSS in Qt:

```
QPushButton {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-style: none;
    font: bold 12px;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
}

QPushButton:focus {
    background-color: blue;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: white;
}
```

**Edit, Solution from Rushi:**
The idea is to define the border for the original (non-focused) button with a transparent color. When it receives focus the width of the button seems to be computed correctly. I don't know why Qt computes it correctly in this case, but it works for me :-)

CSS with the fix:

```
QPushButton {
    background-color: transparent;

    /* we define our border here but with transparent color */
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: transparent;

    font: bold 12px;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
}

QPushButton:focus {
    background-color: blue;
    border-color: white;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear for me why do you use pading? Maybe you should use margin?

Comment: did you try to add `box-sizing:border-box` in your css??

Comment: @Suresh Ponnukalai afaik Qt doesn't support `border-box`

Comment: @Evgeny: margin adds space outside the content and outside the border. Using margin makes the focus highlight smaller. What I want is make the button including the highlight a custom size so I need to use padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Hello Please check below html and css code ,it will be help you to solved this issue.

<html>
    <head>
        <title>title</title>
        <meta charset="windows-1252">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            .box{ background: #000; width: 400px; height: 100px; margin: 50px;  padding: 50px;}
            .QPushButton {
    background-color: transparent;
    font: bold 12px;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
     border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: transparent;

}

.QPushButton:focus {
    background-color: blue;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: white;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box">
            <a href="#" class="QPushButton">3</a>
            <a href="#" class="QPushButton">4</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question about Qt, not about html!

Comment: This answer is actually fine. The idea is to define a transparent border in the first place so that Qt computes the border correctly afterwards. I'm testing right now.

Answer (score 0):

You should decrease size of padding. Here is the trick:

```
QPushButton:focus {
    ....other styles.....
    border-width: 2px;
    padding-left: 6px;
    padding-right: 6px;
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution. If I wanted to have a border of 512px I should be able to. It seems that Qt computes the width of the widget in the wrong way.

Comment: I see, you decreased it exactly by the size of the border. It actually works too, I didn't read the code correctly, so sorry! The accepted answer is better though because one does not have to compute the border by hand which might introduce nasty bugs in the future. Thank you again :-)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer @Evgeny's answer as sometimes you would want border on default state, so setting it to transparent won't help.

A working example:

```
/* default state */
QPushButton {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 1px;
}

QPushButton:hover {
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 0px;
}
```